# Bootstrap carousel not working, puts id on address bar instead

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make the bootstrap carousel work and I'm kind of struggling.

The carousel doesn't automatically start and when I try to click on the arrows in order to change images, it just adds the id of the carousel in the address bar and doesn't change images.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/photos/2.jpg" alt="Band performing">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/photos/1.jpg" alt="Band performing 2">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/photos/3.jpg" alt="Band performing 3">
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Nevo

Comment: Are you including bootstrap.js?

Comment: No I don't. I figured it out 2 minutes after I posted the question... Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, obviously idiotic.

Just forgot to add the bootstrap.js.